# How to detect checked box using python

Tags: python, linux, opencv, image-processing

I have the below PNG image and I am trying to identify which box is checked using Python.

I installed the OMR (optical mark recognition) package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/omr/0.0.7 but it wasn't any help and there wasn't any documentation about OMR.
So I need to know if there is any API or useful package I can use with Python.

Here is my image:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: I guess you are going to have multiple of these images which you are trying to analyse. Is the position of the boxes and number going to be exactly the same (by the pixel) in all images? That would make things far more easy.

Comment: Yes it's always the same format of image, but it's going to be scanned ,so the position of the boxes may vary by a couple of pixels.

Comment: Have you tried OpenCV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not afraid of a little experimenting, the Python Imaging Library (PIL, download from http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ or your favorite repo. Manual: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm) permits loading the PNG, and accessing it.

You can extract a section of the image (eg. the interior of a checkbox. See `crop` in the library), and sum the pixels in that sub-image (see `point`). Compare that with a threshold (say > 10 pixels = checked).

If the PNG comes from scanning forms, you may have to add some positional checking.

Comment: thanks a lot, the idea of summing and comparing pixels was genius and so easy to apply !